# Novice needs help: Bold Font & Text Colour Based on Value

Tags: ios, fonts, colors

I want to make sl.asl bold in the below and colour it based on it's numeric value in the below. Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


// Configure the cell...
ServiceLevel *sl = (ServiceLevel *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", sl.name , sl.asl];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: have a look at my answer below which coveres all your questions about setting a part of your text to bold and covering the ability to change the colour based on numberic values. It's a full explanation on how you can achieve all those things  :) check out. and good luck

Answer (score 1):

Create an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and assign it to `cell.textLabel.attributedText`. For example:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16]
};

NSString *delimiter = @" - ";
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", sl.name, delimiter, sl.asl];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[attributedText addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(sl.name.length + delimiter.length, sl.asl.length)];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Comment: Just for future reference you can create a dynamic length of bold by adding the suffix ` - ` 3 characters with something like this: `NSString *begginingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - ", sl.name];` This way you dont need to have magic numbers like `3` in your code buddy.

Comment: @Pavan, thanks. I updated my example to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: thats fine, its not a problem at all! through collaboration can we produce better code. Speaking of which, I like your delimiter variable naming! I blanked out and couldn't think of a name for the divider, the word `delimiter` is defo the right word to use :D I've implemented the delimiter variable in my answer too now, it makes it all the more easier to edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED CODE - for bolding a part of a text and changing the colour based on a numeric value**

Please d some initial research before you post questions on stackoverflow, and show us what you've tried in the past so that we can help you accordingly.

You can set a part of your text to bold by using the NSAttributedString:
    //To bold a part of a string you have to let it know where you want the bold to start and end from, for that you need to know the length of your `sl.asl` variable

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedAsl = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:sl.asl];

NSString *delimiter = @" - "; //This is what will be written to separate sl.name and sl.asl 
NSString *begginingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", delimiter, sl.name];
//What we dont want bolded
NSInteger startBoldFromEndOfBeginningString = [begginingString length]; 
//The length of text we want bolded - your sl.asl variable
NSInteger slAslLength = ((NSString)sl.asl).length;


UIFont *font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25.0f];
[attributedAsl addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(startBoldFromEndOfBeginningString, slAslLength)];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedAsl;
```

And then you can set the text color like so

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Now if you want to change the textColor based on the numeric value of something you then have to start playing with RGB values which make up color values.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

What will be helpful to ensure an even distribution of colors to the desired range of colours would be to know the highest the number can go to.

Lets say you are displaying the alphabet of the english language in a tableView, the total number of cells would be 26, and you want to change the color of text for each cell displayed, one solution would be to do this:

```
CGFloat maxNumber = 26; //total number of letters
CGFloat dynamicColor = 1.0/maxNumber * indexPath.row;

[UIColor colorWithRed:dynamicColor green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

this will ensure that each textColor is different for each cell that is displayed.

Comment: That won't work because poster wants only part of the string formatted.

Comment: @jonahb Oh thank you for outlining that. He will need to use NSAttributedString then. Will update my answer now.

Comment: Code has been updated to allow for parts of the string to be formatted

Answer (score 1):

An NSAttributedString ought to do the trick.

Like:

```
    NSString *name = @"SampleName";
    NSUInteger asl = 2;
    NSString *t_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %d", name , asl];

    NSUInteger t_nameLength = name.length;
    NSUInteger t_aslLength = 1;

    UIColor *t_color = nil;
    switch (asl) {
        case 1:
            t_color = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            t_color = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        default:
            t_color = [UIColor blackColor];
            break;
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *t_attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:t_string];
    [t_attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, t_nameLength)];
    [t_attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, t_nameLength)];
    [t_attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(t_nameLength + 3, t_aslLength)];
    [t_attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:t_color range:NSMakeRange(t_nameLength + 3, t_aslLength)];

    cell.textLabel.attributedText = t_attributedString;
```

Comment: What does your code do? Please don't just paste code, explain what your code does so that the OP can learn from it instead of him just copying and pasting hoping for things to work.